# What kind of loop works for outputting title and description from xml

Tags: java, xml

I have some code that reads xml from the web and I captured title and description from that as `NodeList`s:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("http://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php");

        NodeList titleNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
        NodeList summaryNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("description");
```

I want to loop through both of them and get output like

> Title
>
> Description
>
> Title
>
> Descripton

I can't get my head around if this is possible with loop as I used nested loop it loop the inner loop for each outer loop any suggestion for any other kinds of loop

Here's an example of the XML: (from http://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Explore California Tours</title>
    <description>Explore Our World Your Way</description>
    <link>http://www.explorecalifornia.org</link>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2011 lynda.com</copyright>
    <item>
      <title>2 Days Adrift the Salton Sea</title>
      <link>http://www.explorecalifornia.org/tour.php?id=14</link>
      <description>The Salton Sea is saltier than the Pacific, an unusual feat for inland body of water. And even though its salinity has risen over the years, due in part to lack of outflows and pollution from agricultural runoff, it has attracted a small, but dedicated population. The sea itself offers recreational opportunities including boating, camping, off-roading, hiking, use of personal watercraft, photography and bird watching. The sea has been termed a "crown jewel of avian biodiversity," being a major resting stop on the Pacific Flyway, a migratory path for birds. 2 Days Adrift the Salton Sea includes two nights accommodations at the Bombay Beach Inn, boat rental at the Salton City Harbor, and a guided fishing tour.</description>
      <category>From Desert to Sea</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>A Week of Wine</title>
      <link>http://www.explorecalifornia.org/tour.php?id=26</link>
      <description>Immerse yourself in the culture and lifestyle of a California winery. Spend 5 days in your private guest villa at the Stockbridge Winery, located in scenic Sonoma. You'll spend your days wandering the vineyards, touring the presses and cellars, and assisting staff in making America's favorite wine. Enjoy Tuscan-style meals served al fresco, overlooking the gorgeous countryside. Day trips include dinner in Sausalito, hiking in the redwood forests, and lunch in downtown San Francisco.</description>
      <category>Taste of California</category>
    </item>
    <!-- ...and so on... -->
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
NodeList itemNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (int i =0; i < itemNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element itemElement = (Element) itemNodes.item(i);
    String title = itemElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
    String description = itemElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();

}
```

Basically, you need to get parent node for both "title" and "description". Then search within ancestors of found nodes.

Comment: This worked for me thanks... this is out of this question anyways I can check if both title and description existed then only print ... in other word to force that only pair must be printed :D

Comment: You can check presence of a tag in this way: `itemElement.getElementsByTagName("title").getLength() > 0`

Comment: Hi, in yesterday feed it work well but today it gives error of (java.lang.NullPointerException) and it point to line number 27 where ( String description = itemElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();) located and idea ?

Comment: `item(0)` returns first found node or null if not found. Most likely the description is missing that's why you are getting NPE. You should check `getLength()` first and if it's not zero then call `item(0).getTextContent()`

Answer (score 1):

If there are the same number of titles and descriptions, and you want to output them in parallel, then a simple loop is all you need:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < titleNodes.length; ++i) {
    // output titleNodes[i] here
    // output descriptionNodes[i] here
}
```

More likely, though, there's a container element that has both of those in it, and you'd be better off looping through the container elements and then looking within each one for the title and description.

**Edit** *(once you posted the XML)*: For instance, in this case, you probably want to loop through the `item` elements and then retrieve their title and description as you loop:

```
for (Element element : doc.getElementsByTagName("item")) {
    // Output element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0) here
    // Output element.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0) here
}
```

Depending on what DOM library you're using, you might be able to use `element.querySelector("title")` rather than `element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0)` (and similarly for document).

---

Note that I changed the names of the variables (made them plural, e.g. `titleNodes` rather than `titleNode`), as they are lists, not individual nodes.

Comment: nope... there is only one extra element (title) in XML which is website title that is why it messing up the out put...at start of XLM there is an extra title tag.... any solution for that?

Comment: @hi4ppl: 10 minutes prior to your comment I updated the answer with a solution for that. See "**Edit**". The general suggestion of using a parent container element was there even prior to that.

Comment: i'm using java's default parser here is complete code... your solution it says it can only iterate over array I think Java parser is not array it read bites per bite I think not sure i'm new in Java world...
I update the code in question...the xml example I posted is only one...there are other xml that does not have pairs of them... I want to be able to check if pairs if possible?

Comment: @hi4ppl: I've shown you how to do it with pairs (if there's one more or less of one vs. the other and you know that, then just use the handy `+` or `-` operators [e.g., `.item(i + 1)` or similar] when retrieving one of them as appropriate). If `NodeList` is `Iterable`, then you can use the enhanced for loop I've shown for `items`. There's no better way to get the code going than to get really hands-on with it yourself, understand what you're doing, read documentation, read tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
NodeList itemNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (int i = 0; i < itemNode.getLength(); i++) {
  Element itemEle = (Element)itemNode.item(i);
  // You chould check if there is a title/description element, I'm skipping this for brevity
  Element titleEle = (Element)itemEle.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);
  Element descrEle = (Element)itemEle.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);
  // Output them, now you're sure you are in the same pair
}
```